# MainActivity.java action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse

This is the only error I have now in my MainActivity.java. 
The line "if (id == R.id.action_settings)" which is created by eclipse gives the error :"action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field"
I appreciate your help to solve it

```
 package chapter.two.hello_world;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 WorldGen earth = new WorldGen("Earth", 5973, 9.78);

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setStartUpWorldValues();
    }

 protected void setStartUpWorldValues(){
    earth.setPlanetColonies(1);
    earth.setPlanetMilitary(1);
    earth.setColonyImmigration(1000);
    earth.setBaseProtection(100);
    earth.turnForceFieldOn();
    }

 protected void setStartUpScreenText(){
    TextView planetNameValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView1);
    planetNameValue.setText(earth.planetName);
    TextView planetMassValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView2);
    planetMassValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMass));
    TextView planetGravityValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView3);
    planetGravityValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetGravity));
    TextView planetColoniesValue =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView4);
    planetColoniesValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetColonies));
    TextView planetPopulationValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView5);
    planetPopulationValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetPopulation));
    TextView planetMilitaryValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView6);
    planetMilitaryValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetMilitary));
    TextView planetBaseValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView7);
    planetBaseValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetBases));
    TextView planetForceFieldValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dataView8);
    planetForceFieldValue.setText(String.valueOf(earth.planetProtection));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) { // the error is here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }
```

Comment: had you checked your menu.xml that actionsetting is there or not.?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your R.menu.main xml file does not contain an item having @+id/action_settings as its id. Check your R.menu.main xml file ans make sure the action_settings id is set.

Comment: I am very new to android. Would you please explain more what should I do?

Comment: If you are not using any item in the action bar, just remove the content of the onOptionItemSelected method and leave "return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);" only.

Answer (score 1):

As say Quanturium this mean you don't have an item with this name. But as you are talking about "action_setting" you're in fact talking about special item which are not commonly in the XML main file.

*Note: I'm not a "pro" in Android, so I just hope this will help.*

Have a look at the folder on the left of Android Studio. You have one named "res". Inside you have drawable, values etc... Do you have one named "menu"?
If not create one: clic right on "res", select "New / Android ressource directory" and give "menu" as name.
Now we have a folder which will contain the data for our menu, like action_settings etc...

Now, clic right on this new folder and select "New / Menu ressource file". 
The name you'll give must be the name of the activity.
Eg you have a Java piece of code named "Creation", the activity (in the layout folder) is named "activity_creation.xml", so in the menu folder you have to give "creation" as name of the file, which will be created as "creation.xml".

Now, in this file you have to write:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="net.XXX.YYY.ZZZZ" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

where XXXX and YYYY are the directory of your app (same as yu write in top of yur Java code), and ZZZZ is the name of the activity (so in my example "creation")

As know you have a "menu", and an action_settings, in your code the following lines will be OK:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Understanding the goal of each folder in Android is a bit hard but necessary as a lot of "smalls problems" came from that.